# Laravel: Click event on tab pane

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have tables called: 1) purchase_requisitions; 2) liquidations. Assuming that I have 100 data for both purchase requisitions and liquidations.

In our application, we have all the lists of users and when the client clicked a certain user, there will be a modal that will pop-up.

In this modal you can see all the records for that user and also there's 2 tab. 1) Purchase Requisition tab; 2) Liquidations tab.

Purchase Requisition is the active tab once the client clicked the certain user and this is where I'm fetching the data of purchase requisitions.

Now what I want is, I dont want to load the 100 data of purchase requisitions and liquidations at the same time.

I want to load the liquidations, for example when I clicked the liquidations tab.

Question: Why does my click event is not working?

**Tab pane**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="nav-item" style="width: 10%">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#purchases-payments-tab">Purchases/Payments</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" style="width: 10%">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#liquidations-tab">Liquidations</a>
</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPurchasesPayments(vendor_id,start_date,end_date){
    // .... code
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vendor_id                                          = "<?= $vendor->id; ?>";
    var start_date                                         = "<?= $start_date;?>";
    var end_date                                           = "<?= $end_date;?>";
    if ($('.purchases-payments').length > 0) {
        $('div').click('.purchases-payments',function(e){ 
        // $('.purchases-payments').click(function(e){ 
            $('.purchases-payments-details').html('');
            getPurchasesPayments(vendor_id,start_date,end_date);
            
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        })
    }

    if ($('.liquidations').length > 0) {
        $('div').click('.liquidations',function(e){
        // $('.liquidations').click(function(e){
            alert('test');
            
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        })
    }

    // if ($('.liquidations').hasClass('active')) {
    //     alert('liquidations active');
    // }
})
```

Comment: Where are these selector in page: `$('.purchases-payments')` , `$('.liquidations')` ?
You need to specity more  `$('div')` because there are many `div` s

Comment: Tips: use `console.log(something)` step by step

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting "div" in your jQuery click code, but you want to target your `a` elements, you should also add classes or ids to this elements which you will be targeting.

Add ids to your `a` elements

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item" style="width: 10%">
        <a id="purchases" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#purchases-payments-tab">Purchases/Payments</a>
    </li>
    <li id="liquidations" class="nav-item" style="width: 10%">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#liquidations-tab">Liquidations</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#purchases').click(function(e){ 
        // your code 
    });
    $('#liquidations').click(function(e){ 
        // your code 
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed it also. I already did that but now, my tab is not working. anymore. I checked the console, there's no error

Comment: Why is your tab not working, what else did you change? I assume you removed `href` attribute. It's required for tabs to work properly.